# fs.readFileSync is not file relative? Node.js

Tags: node.js, path

Suppose I have a file at the root of my project called `file.xml`.

Suppose I have a test file in tests/ called "test.js" and it has

```
const file = fs.readFileSync("../file.xml");
```

If I now run `node ./tests/test.js` from the root of my project it says `../file.xml` does not exist. If I run the same command from within the tests directory, then it works.

It seems `fs.readFileSync` is relative to the directory where the script is invoked from, instead of where the script actually is. If I wrote `fs.readFileSync("./file.xml")` in `test.js` it would look more confusing and is not consistent with relative paths in a `require` statement which are file relative.

Why is this? How can I avoid having to rewrite the paths in my `fs.readFileSync`?

Comment: `__dirname` is not necessarily the same as the current working directory, but `fs.readFileSync()` uses the current working directory.  The current working directory is likely set to whatever it was when you launched node.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

You can resolve the path relative the location of the source file - rather than the current directory - using [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths):

```
const path = require("path");
const file = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../file.xml"));
```

Comment: Because relative paths are resolved using the current directory. And you want to resolve using a different directory. From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html): *"The relative path to a filename can be used. Remember, however, that this path will be relative to process.cwd()."*

Comment: for some reason I got it into my head that because local file wasn't working on my remote environment that i . would need to get the file by a full url. However, of course I didn't and I was able to use this method to resolve the absolute path on my remote server..

Comment: Note - [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) is a node module that provides utilities for working with file and directory paths. [`__dirname`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname) is a node.js environment variable that point to the parent directory of the current file.

Comment: I will just add to take a look at the cosole... maybe some "../" is missing. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 17):

Just to expand on the above, if you are using [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) with [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) (and of course CommonJS) here's the syntax:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const logo = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/img/logo.svg'));
```

This is because `fs.readFileSync()` is resolved relative to the current working directory, see the [Node.js File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_string_paths) docs for more info.

Source: [Relative fs.readFileSync paths with Node.js](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/relative-paths-with-node-readfilesync)

And of course, the CommonJS format:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const logo = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/img/logo.svg'));
```

Comment: Not sure I see how this expands the accepted answer, it seems exactly the same to me - `path.resolve` with `__dirname` and a relative path.

Comment: @404 Yes I was including for TypeScript folks :) the code is the same but using import statements.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative if you are using `type module` is to use `process.cwd()`

package.json

```js
{
    "type": "module",
}
```

`console.log(process.cwd() + relative_path) // /User/your_user/path_to_folder`

Comment: This worked for my Svelte project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES modules (`"type": "module"`), you can get the module path from [`import.meta.url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta#url):

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { dirname, resolve } from 'path'
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'

const modulePath = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

const file = readFileSync(resolve(modulePath, '../file.xml'))
```