# Node JS - no such file or directory filesystem module

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I'm trying to use an email template while sending emails. here's my project structure.

```
project-name
  client
  server
    email-templates
      confirm-email.html
    controllers
      accounts.js (currently here)
```

I am reading the template file like so.

```
fs.readFile('../email-templates/confirm-email.html', async (error, html) => {
  // do some stuff
})
```

I think have entered a correct path. but still I get an error.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

I have checked other questions on SO. but they are using the variable `__dirname` because I am using ES6 modules I don't have access to that variable.

```
// package.json
"type": "module",
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600943/fs-readfilesync-is-not-file-relative-node-js

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `path` module to resolve the absolute path the file when you are trying to access the file.

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../email-templates/confirm-email.html'), function(err, html) {// do some stuff})
```

Comment: I'm using es6 modules. I don't have access to `__dirname` variable.

Comment: It is strange, every Node.js module should have `__dirname` variable. You need fix that.

Comment: I have `"type": "module",` in my `package.json` that's why

Comment: @vajad57 you can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag
Try using the URL file access notation to build the correct `__dirname` for your case

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to `__dirname` because I'm using ES6 modules. I've used `path.resolve()` instead which fixed the error.

```
fs.readFile(
  path.join(path.resolve(), 'email-templates', 'confirm-email.html'),
  'utf8',
  (error, html) => {
    // do some stuff
  }
);
```

to get access of the `__dirname` variable when can do:

```
const __dirname = path.resolve();
```