# MongoDb deployment automation in docker

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, devops

I want to automate the process of deploying a mongo database image and then creating a user etc. I have the following working option, `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:

 mongo-sa:
  image: mongo:4.4
  container_name: local-mongo-sa
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/mongo-sa/data/db:/data/db
    - ./volumes/mongo-sa/data/configdb:/data/configdb
    - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and `init-mongodb.js` in `scripts` folder:

```
dbAdmin = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
dbAdmin.createUser({
  user: "admin",
  pwd: "retranslatorAdmin",
  roles: [{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }],
  mechanisms: ["SCRAM-SHA-256"],
});
```

As I indicated above, this option works correctly. But I have a need to store certain parameters such as database name, username, etc. in a separate configuration file `config.json` like this:

```
{
    "DbHost": "localhost",
    "DbName": "admin",
    "DbPass": "retranslatorAdmin",
    "DbAuth": "SCRAM-SHA-256"
}
```

thus i want my script `init-mongodb.js` received data from `config.json` and substituted into the function `dbAdmin.createUser(...)`

i did it like this

```
import fs from 'fs';

const configContent = fs.readFileSync('../configs/config.json');
const config = JSON.parse(configContent);

console.log(config);

dbAdmin = db.getSiblingDB(config.DbName);
dbAdmin.createUser({
  user: config.DbName,
  pwd: config.DbPass,
  roles: [{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: config.DbName }],
  mechanisms: [config.DbAuth],
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how to do it right?

Comment: Does the `console.log` show the `JSON` content of the file?

Comment: Variable `config` is an existing variable (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/configure-shell-settings/), maybe try a different name.

Comment: @BadPiggie i'm not strong in node, but in this way i tried to see if the script works - nothing happens

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit don't work

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600943/fs-readfilesync-is-not-file-relative-node-js